# Django: How to join tables based on a lookup tables' value

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I am trying to do what one might consider an advanced sql query and would like to know if its possible in Django without resorting to raw sql (I will if its necessary).

I want to join 1 or another table based on a value located in a table lookup table and would like to do this entirely in python/django.

The following are rough examples of the models I am using:

```
class SpecificProduct(models.Model):
    specific_product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    a_field = models.TextField()
    something_specific_to_this_model = models.CharField()


class GeneralProduct(models.Model):
    other_product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()

TABLE_CATEGORIES = {
    1 : SpecificProduct,
    2 : GeneralProduct,
}

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    table_category = models.IntegerField()  # Technically represents a table.
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_pk = models.IntegerField()  # Technically foreign key to a product table.
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

What I want is a method like:

```
def get_product(category_id, product_pk):
    # SQL query  magic
    return one_object_of_a_specific_product_type
```

This method should be able to do things like...

- Give me the product (model) where the `product_category = 1` and the
  `product_pk = 1`. (returns a SpecificProduct model)
- Give me the product    where `product_category = 2` and the `product_pk = 50`
  (returns a    GeneralProduct model)

How do you do this query in Django and is this even possible?

**Edit:**
Based on Kireeti K's response I have created models that look like the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey


class SpecificProduct(models.Model):
    specific_product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    specific_text = models.TextField()

class GeneralProduct(models.Model):
    general_product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()

class ProductCategoryLookup(models.Model):
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    product = GenericForeignKey('product_category', 'product_id')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()


def get_product(category_id, product_pk):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(id=category_id)
    inventory = Inventory.objects.get(product_category=content_type, product_id=product_pk).first()
    return inventory.product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic-foreign-key to get foreign-key relation with any model sort of dynamically, read about it here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

If you rewrite your models using generic-foreign-key then it looks something like this.

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    table_category = models. GenericForeignKey()  # Technically represents a table.
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, 
                       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    product = models. GenericForeignKey()  # Technically foreign key to a product table.
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Now to achieve what you want, you can implement your function like this.

```
def get_product(model=None, category_id, product_pk):
    model = "specificproduct" if model else "generalproduct"
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=model)
    inventory = Inventory.objects.get(product_category_id=category_id, object_id=product_pk, content_type=content_type)

    return inventory.product
```

Comment: This does achieve what i am looking for, although I made heavy changes, cleaning up some of what you've done here. I will be including them above in the question. Thanks for helping me out. I didn't know about ContentType and GenericForeignKey

Comment: @Mike glad it helped